# Exclude Node in semPaths {semPlot}

Tags: r, structural-equation-model, semplot

I'm trying to plot a sem-path with R.

Im using an OUT file provinent from Mplus with semPaths {semPLot}.

Apparently it seems to work, but i want to remove some latent variables and i don't know how.

I am using the following syntax :

Out from Mplus : https://www.dropbox.com/s/vo3oa5fqp7wydlg/questedMOD2.out?dl=0

````
outfile1 <- "questedMOD.out"
```

semPaths(outfile1,what="est", intercepts=FALSE, rotation=4,  edge.color="black", sizeMan=5, esize=TRUE, structural="TRUE",  layout="tree2", nCharNodes=0, intStyle="multi" )
````

Comment: Show us the data structure. Try posting output of `str(x)` or even better, make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've just uploaded the OUTfile from Mplus. Thank you for your advice :)

Comment: I suggest you 'embed' the code into your answer so that the question doesn't go obsolete once you remove the file from Dropbox.

Comment: I am not allowed to do that :( But the general thing is that happened with all data sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be an easier way to do this (and ignoring if it is sensible to do it) - one way you can do this is by removing nodes from the object prior to plotting.

Using the Mplus example from your question [Rotate Edges in semPaths/qgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587151/rotate-edges-in-sempaths-qgraph)

```
library(qgraph)
library(semPlot)
library(MplusAutomation)

# This downloads an output file from Mplus examples
download.file("http://www.statmodel.com/usersguide/chap5/ex5.8.out", 
                                        outfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".out"))

# Unadjusted plot
s <- semPaths(outfile, intercepts = FALSE)
```

[image]

In the above call to `semPaths`, `outfile` is of class `character`, so the line (near the start of code for `semPaths`)

```
 if (!"semPlotModel" %in% class(object)) 
                    object <- do.call(semPlotModel, c(list(object), modelOpts))
```

returns the object from `semPlot:::semPlotModel.mplus.model(outfile)`. This is of class `"semPlotModel"`.

So the idea is to create this object first, amend it and then pass this object to `semPaths`.

```
# Call semPlotModel on your Mplus file
obj <- semPlot:::semPlotModel.mplus.model(outfile)
# obj <- do.call(semPlotModel, list(outfile)) # this is more general / not just for Mplus

# Remove one factor (F1) from object@Pars - need to check lhs and rhs columns
idx <- apply(obj@Pars[c("lhs", "rhs")], 1, function(i) any(grepl("F1", i)))
obj@Pars <- obj@Pars[!idx, ]

class(obj)
```

`obj` is now of class `"semPlotModel"` and can be passed directly to `semPaths`

```
s <- semPaths(obj, intercepts = FALSE)
```

[image]

You can use `str(s)` to see the structure of this returned object.

Comment: That is not exactly what i needed but I think is a good clue and now i can't do it myself. Thanks :)

Comment: you're welcome - i didnt know of this package so ive been plotting these models manually with graphviz - so im very happy you asked this question.

Comment: I kind of solve it this question some days ago in a "rude" way, but that's better :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use the following sempath code to print your SEM

```
semPaths(obj, intercepts = FALSE)%>%
   plot()
```

you can use the following function to remove any node by its label:

```
remove_nodes_and_edges <- function(semPaths_obj,node_tbrm_vec){
   
   relevent_nodes_index <- semPaths_obj$graphAttributes$Nodes$names %in% node_tbrm_vec

   semPaths_obj$graphAttributes$Nodes$width[relevent_nodes_index]=0

   semPaths_obj$graphAttributes$Nodes$height[relevent_nodes_index]=0
   
   semPaths_obj$graphAttributes$Nodes$labels[relevent_nodes_index]=""

   return(semPaths_obj)

}
```

and use this function in the plotting pipe in the following way

```
semPaths(obj, intercepts = FALSE) %>%
   remove_nodes_and_edges(c("Y1","Y2","Y3")) %>%
   plot()
```