# Rotate Edges in semPaths/qgraph

Tags: r, path, diagram

I have a data that looks similar to  this exemple of Sasha Epskamp:

```
library(qgraph)
library(semPlot)
library(MplusAutomation)

download.file("http://www.statmodel.com/usersguide/chap5/ex5.8.out", outfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".out"))

# Plot model:
semPaths(outfile, intercepts = FALSE)
```

[image]

I would like to "rotate" the semi-circular "Edges" for each Node. For semi-circular edges I mean the edges that normally contains complementary R^2 squares. I don't know how that is called, so it's quite impossible for me to solve this problem for my own.  If more information is required, don't hesitate to ask for it.

Comment: I don't know what edge you want to change - do you mean the residual variance on the Y-nodes - can you give an example of which node the edges go in / out of please. Might also be useful to add a link to the example you mention.

Comment: I mean the residual variancies in Y, and also in F1 and F2.  I can't add my data due to confidenciality... :(, but that one from Sasha is a good example

Comment: ok, by rotate, do you mean have the edge on, for example, the right hand side of the node?

Comment: Yes. I mean for example, Having exactly the same  "direction" in Y1 than in F1 (in that case even if it's covering the other line)

Answer (score 0):

There is a rotate argument in semPath.
With semPath(outfile, rotation = 2) you can change the rotation of the layout. You can also specify different layout-styles with the layout = ""
argument.
I believe this page would be very helpfull for you to see what other semPath arguments you need:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/semPlot/versions/1.1.2/topics/semPaths